# Multidimensional array fetch using curl shows invalid argument in foreach

Tags: php

I have an array like this which I fetch using file_get_content and here is other side url ([http://sample.com/change.php)code](http://sample.com/change.php%29code) from where I fetch array.

```
$a=array();
$a=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT *
FROM tablename
LIMIT 0 , 2
;");

$a=(array)$a;
print_r($a);
```

Then i use

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://sample.com/change.php');
```

That is the output of $result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_stock_available] => 1
            [id_product] => 1
            [id_product_attribute] => 0
            [id_shop] => 1
            [id_shop_group] => 0
            [quantity] => 3
            [depends_on_stock] => 0
            [out_of_stock] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_stock_available] => 2
            [id_product] => 2
            [id_product_attribute] => 0
            [id_shop] => 1
            [id_shop_group] => 0
            [quantity] => 1
            [depends_on_stock] => 0
            [out_of_stock] => 2
        )

)
```

When I apply foreach for $result:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    //var_dump($value['installed'];
}
```

it shows me `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: try to check `var_dump($result)` first

Comment: It shows me output string(614) "Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_stock_available] => 1 [id_product] => 1 [id_product_attribute] => 0 [id_shop] => 1 [id_shop_group] => 0 [quantity] => 3 [depends_on_stock] => 0 [out_of_stock] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id_stock_available] => 2 [id_product] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => 0 [id_shop] => 1 [id_shop_group] => 0 [quantity] => 1 [depends_on_stock] => 0 [out_of_stock] => 2 ) ) "

Comment: have your tried this? $result = (array) $result; then do a var_dump again

Comment: if you look carefully, `$result` is actually a string. it says on your `var_dump`

Comment: @GianCarlo  it shows me array(1) { [0]=> string(614) "Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_stock_available] => 1 [id_product] => 1 [id_product_attribute] => 0 [id_shop] => 1 [id_shop_group] => 0 [quantity] => 3 [depends_on_stock] => 0 [out_of_stock] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id_stock_available] => 2 [id_product] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => 0 [id_shop] => 1 [id_shop_group] => 0 [quantity] => 1 [depends_on_stock] => 0 [out_of_stock] => 2 ) ) " }  now foreach invaid argument not showing but it is also showing correct array in foreach loop like am using foreach ($result as $csv) {}

Comment: @kevinabelita ok Please let me know how we can convert it as an array

Comment: check your curl if it is returning an array and not a string.

Comment: Am using file_get_contents now and from url file am using $a=array();
$a=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT *
FROM `ps_stock_available`
LIMIT 0 , 2
;");
  
$a=(array)$a;


print_r($a); Plz lemme know anything wrong here?

Comment: its hard to guess whats on the other side of the code, try to post other relevant codes to be examined.

Comment: $a=array();
$a=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT *
FROM `ps_stock_available`
LIMIT 0 , 2
;");
  
$a=(array)$a;


print_r($a); it is other side code and I have tried also  file_get_contents now but same thing happening...

Comment: i mean add it on the main question, not here on the comments section, properly construct it again with your code from the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your php file you must change it to this:

```
// your query here
$a = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 0 , 2;");
// then output it as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($a);
```

Then to get it on the other php:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://sample.com/change.php');
$values = json_decode($result, true);
```

The values should be on `$values` as an array

Comment: Your welcome and no problem, so a tip: next time try to add and post relevant code, because this might be very helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: @user3450650 Also read-up on why singleton is bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/is-there-a-use-case-for-singletons-with-database-access-in-php/4596323#4596323

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` returns the content of response (*return false on fail*), which is a **string**, but not an **array**.

You have to parse the result of `print_r` back to array, which is not a good idea.

So use some encode/decode strategy to do this:

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

and

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://sample.com/change.php');
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is not a proper way for serializing data for Web Services because serializing data means that it should be deserialized on the receiving end. As you know there's not a function that *deserializes* data outputted by `print_r` i.e. takes a string created by `print_r` and returning `array` that was passed in. Also from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

*Human-readable* doesn't mean *computer-readable* as well.

You have 2 alternatives:

1. php's [`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

   ```
   // web service.
   $a=(array)$a;
   serialize($a);

   // receiving end.
   $result = file_get_contents('http://sample.com/change.php');
   var_dump(unserialize($result);
   ```
2. [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

   ```
   // web service.
   $a=(array)$a;
   json_encode($a);

   // receiving end.
   $result = file_get_contents('http://sample.com/change.php');
   var_dump(json_decode($result);
   ```

I recommend using `json` because almost every platform can be client of your web service. While with native serializing, consumer of your WS will be client written in php also.

Comment: @user3450650 You're welcome. You need to mark answer which helped you with a tick on the left hand-side of answer.